# Token received by RemotePushIOS cannot be set as a State

Tags: ios, react-native, state

I'm using RemotePushIOS to get the Device Token.

```
RemotePushIOS.requestPermissions(function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Could not register for push");
    } else {
        console.log(data.token);
        var value = "v"+data.token;

        console.log("VALUE: " + value);
        this.setState({
            deviceToken: value
        });
    }
});
```

The `console.log` prints the token but when setting the `state` with the token, program crashes with the following error.

```
'undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.setState')'
```

Why is this happening? What is the workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is, that your `this` reference is not pointing to your component.

In order to avoid the `this` reference getting bound to the callback function, you can use an ES6 arrow function instead of the function keyword.

Replace

```
RemotePushIOS.requestPermissions(function(err, data) {
```

With

```
RemotePushIOS.requestPermissions((err, data) => {
```

ES6 arrow functions are lexically scoped, so the `this` inside the function will point to the context outside the function, which, assuming you are executing this code inside a method of you component, will be referring to your component.

Comment: Thank you. This fixed the problem.